# How to see when the last time a specific block of code or if condition was used in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, jvm

I'd like to find redundant blocks of code in my service. Is there a way to check when that last time this code was used runtime? The service is running on GCP.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "redundant blocks of code" and how do you want to identify them based on the "last time this code was code"?

Comment: @JurajMartinka, if a code was not in use, let's say in the last x months/years. It should raise a flag. It means that no flow is getting there.

Comment: I see, you should then clarify your question - this is an important information in understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a great solution to your problem but you could instrument, perhaps via Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP), selected places in your code with simple logging statements and then monitor those.

You should avoid including *any* "hot code" which is executed very frequently because you can slow down your service and produce an overwhelming amount of logs (harder to manage and costly).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of way to do this, but personally, I would use logging into this function and then let this app running normally. Then, you'll just have to check you log files and check for your logging message occurrences.

However, I'm not sure if it is possible to get this information without any action of your part to see previous usages of your code block.

Comment: It is a skinny solution, I'd like to have statistics about all the applications (code in it)